# How to save image without cropping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, cropperjs

I'm using **Dropzonejs** with **Cropperjs**. The current flow is select an image, crop it and save it.

[image]

I want to select an image and give user two options

1) Crop then save

2) Cancel crop and save it without cropping.

The first option is available by default in cropperjs. But How can I add a `cancel` button which should send the image to dropzone without cropping. In simple words I want the original selected image in dropzone.

**Dropzone JS Configuration Code:**

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
// Dropzone Configurations
var dropzone = new Dropzone('#story-thumbnail-dropzone-upload', {
  parallelUploads: 1,
  thumbnailHeight: 120,
  thumbnailWidth: 120,
  // Number of Files to allow for UPLOAD
  maxFiles:1,
  init: function() {
        this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
              this.removeAllFiles();
              this.addFile(file);
        });
  },
  transformFile: function(file, done) {

        var myDropZone = this;

        // Create the image editor overlay
        var editor = document.createElement('div');
        editor.style.position = 'fixed';
        editor.style.left = 0;
        editor.style.right = 0;
        editor.style.top = 0;
        editor.style.bottom = 0;
        editor.style.zIndex = 9999;
        editor.style.backgroundColor = '#000';

        // Create the confirm button
        var confirm = document.createElement('button');
        confirm.style.position = 'absolute';
        confirm.style.left = '10px';
        confirm.style.top = '10px';
        confirm.style.zIndex = 9999;
        confirm.textContent = 'Crop';
        confirm.addEventListener('click', function() {

            // Get the canvas with image data from Cropper.js
            var canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
                width: 256,
                height: 256
            });

            // Turn the canvas into a Blob (file object without a name)
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {

                // Update the image thumbnail with the new image data
                myDropZone.createThumbnail(
                    blob,
                    myDropZone.options.thumbnailWidth,
                    myDropZone.options.thumbnailHeight,
                    myDropZone.options.thumbnailMethod,
                    false,
                    function(dataURL) {

                        // Update the Dropzone file thumbnail
                        myDropZone.emit('thumbnail', file, dataURL);

                        // Return modified file to dropzone
                        done(blob);
                    }
                );

            });

            // Remove the editor from view
            editor.parentNode.removeChild(editor);

        });
        editor.appendChild(confirm);

        // Load the image
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        editor.appendChild(image);

        // Append the editor to the page
        document.body.appendChild(editor);

        // Create Cropper.js and pass image
        var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
            aspectRatio: 1
        });

    },
  filesizeBase: 1000,
  thumbnail: function(file, dataUrl) {
    if (file.previewElement) {
      file.previewElement.classList.remove("dz-file-preview");
      var images = file.previewElement.querySelectorAll("[data-dz-thumbnail]");
      for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var thumbnailElement = images[i];
        thumbnailElement.alt = file.name;
        thumbnailElement.src = dataUrl;
      }
      setTimeout(function() { file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-image-preview"); }, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dropzone needsclick" id="story-thumbnail-dropzone-upload" action="/admin/upload-story-thumbnail">
  <div class="dz-message needsclick">
    Drop files here or click to upload.<BR>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsbin snippet with cdn links? CDN links are missing from your code.

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai there is an ajax request I don't think JSBIN is possible for this! CDN are latest dropzone and cropperjs cdn links!

Comment: @Iftikharuddin i facing slow while uploading images , did you face that too ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly do it by preserving the original file in a global variable easily and then pass that onto dropzone upon click event on your cancel button. I have modified the code and did it for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/4.0.0/cropper.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/min/dropzone.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.1/cropper.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="dropzone needsclick" id="story-thumbnail-dropzone-upload" action="/admin/upload-story-thumbnail">
    <div class="dz-message needsclick">
    Drop files here or click to upload.<BR>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
  
<script>
var originalFile = null;
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
// Dropzone Configurations
var dropzone = new Dropzone('#story-thumbnail-dropzone-upload', {
    parallelUploads: 1,
    thumbnailHeight: 120,
    thumbnailWidth: 120,
    // Number of Files to allow for UPLOAD
    maxFiles: 1,
    init: function() {
        this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
            this.removeAllFiles();
            this.addFile(file);
        });
    },
    transformFile: function(file, done) {
      
      originalFile = file;

        var myDropZone = this;

        // Create the image editor overlay
        var editor = document.createElement('div');
        editor.classList.add('cropCanvas');
        editor.style.position = 'fixed';
        editor.style.left = 0;
        editor.style.right = 0;
        editor.style.top = 0;
        editor.style.bottom = 0;
        editor.style.zIndex = 9999;
        editor.style.backgroundColor = '#000';

        // Create the confirm button
        var confirm = document.createElement('button');
        confirm.style.left = '10px';
        confirm.style.top = '10px';
        confirm.style.zIndex = 9999;
        confirm.textContent = 'Crop';
        confirm.addEventListener('click', function() {

            // Get the canvas with image data from Cropper.js
            var canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
                width: 256,
                height: 256
            });

            // Turn the canvas into a Blob (file object without a name)
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {

                // Update the image thumbnail with the new image data
                myDropZone.createThumbnail(
                    blob,
                    myDropZone.options.thumbnailWidth,
                    myDropZone.options.thumbnailHeight,
                    myDropZone.options.thumbnailMethod,
                    false,
                    function(dataURL) {

                        // Update the Dropzone file thumbnail
                        myDropZone.emit('thumbnail', file, dataURL);

                        // Return modified file to dropzone
                        done(blob);
                      console.log(blob);
                    }
                );

            });

            // Remove the editor from view
            editor.parentNode.removeChild(editor);

        });
        
        // Create the cancel button
        var cancel = document.createElement('button');
        cancel.style.position = 'absolute';
        cancel.style.left = '50px';
        cancel.style.top = '0px';
        cancel.style.zIndex = 9999;
        cancel.textContent = 'Cancel';
        cancel.style.position = 'absolute';
        cancel.addEventListener('click', function() {

         done(originalFile);

         // Remove the editor from view
         editor.parentNode.removeChild(editor);

        });
        editor.appendChild(confirm);
        editor.appendChild(cancel);

        // Load the image
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        // Just added width for not having extra space to show the image in a limited available space
        // REMOVE THIS THEN!!!!
        image.width = '500px';
        editor.appendChild(image);

        // Append the editor to the page
        document.body.appendChild(editor);

        // Create Cropper.js and pass image
        var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
            aspectRatio: 1
        });

    },
    filesizeBase: 1000,
    thumbnail: function(file, dataUrl) {
        if (file.previewElement) {
            file.previewElement.classList.remove("dz-file-preview");
            var images = file.previewElement.querySelectorAll("[data-dz-thumbnail]");
            for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                var thumbnailElement = images[i];
                thumbnailElement.alt = file.name;
                thumbnailElement.src = dataUrl;
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
                file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-image-preview");
            }, 1);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for that answer , it's help me , but when use it from smaller pc , take long time for uploading

Comment: i found if i add , 'image/jpeg' to canvas.toBlob , that's tell to browser to make it blod jpg for default  , without it  browser use png as a defult blob